# Why is apache2 failed?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, apache2, failed-to-connect

Whenever I check the status for XAMPP with

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp status
```

I get that everything is running at the moment.
But when I use this command:

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

Get this output:

```
 apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-12-19 17:10:06 EET; 41s ago
  Process: 11150 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16555 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 11108 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

 19 17:10:06  apachectl[16555]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified 
 19 17:10:06  apachectl[16555]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [:
 19 17:10:06  apachectl[16555]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.
 19 17:10:06  apachectl[16555]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
 19 17:10:06  apachectl[16555]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
 19 17:10:06  apachectl[16555]: Action 'start' failed.
 19 17:10:06  apachectl[16555]: The Apache error log may have more information.
 19 17:10:06  systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
 19 17:10:06  systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 19 17:10:06  systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Why is this happening and how to solve it?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: You will need to check the `error.log` in order to get a complete error report. However, looking at the messages, it seems another application is already listening to the ports that your XAMPP installation is trying to grab. Does your system have nginx or Apache installed (not as part of XAMPP)? 